# Objective C calling Java methods using JNI

Tags: java, objective-c, methods, java-native-interface

Can someone show me how to call a Java method from Objective C.

In more detail this is actually what I would like to do

1) Have first call from the java side to the objective C. during this call I would like to get a reference to the java object.

2) Later down the line I would like Objective C to use the reference got in the previous step to call Java methods.

Thanks

Comment: Objective C is a proper superset of C, so whatever code you have working in C, just port over and run it in ObjC.

Comment: What makes you think I have C code. :-)

Comment: Well actually I do and it is one of the approaches that I am willing to take. 

But the C code that I have is complicated. There are a lot of other stuff that is being done in C and there is a lot of coupling, it is hard for me to follow and just do the same.

Also I was hoping to keep the entire code in Objective C

Comment: You don't have to change the C code to objective-c, just put it in your project and call it.

Answer (score 5):

The following seems to work. It is based on the above comment on following the C examples and this link.

http://urlgrey.net/?p=121

As the link says do not create a global variable for the env instead create a global variable of the jvm, also create a global reference to your class.

Here is how I implement the step 1 :
"
1) Have first call from the java side to the objective C. during this call I would like to get a reference to the java object.
"

First declare global variable in the header file for

1) the jvm:

```
JavaVM *jvm;
```

2) The Java class:

```
jclass smartCallbackClass;
```

3) The java Object:

```
jobject smartCallbackObject;
```

Next in the call that comes from the Java side to the Objective C set the values for these variables

1) For the JVM:

```
(*env)->GetJavaVM(env, &jvm);
```

2) For the Object:

```
smartCallbackObject = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, obj);
```

3) For the Class:

```
if (smartCallbackClass == NULL) {
    jclass localRefCls = (*env)->FindClass(env,"com/studyisland/nativelibs/smart/responsesdk/interfaces/thin/SMARTResponseThinClient"); 
    if (localRefCls == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to create a JNI Java Class reference \n");
    }
    //Create a global reference for JNI Java class
    smartCallbackClass = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env,localRefCls);

    //Delete the local reference as it is no longer needed
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, localRefCls);

    //Is the global reference created successfully?
    if (smartCallbackClass == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to create JNI Java class reference \n");
        return 0;
    }       
}
```

Here is the link from where I got the code for the class

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/refs.html

Now the second step

"
2) Later down the line I would like Objective C to use the reference got in the previous step to call Java methods
"

To call from Objective C back to Java you need to make sure that the call is done on the same thread by which Java called Objective C, so here is the code.

```
-(void)classFailedToStop:(SMARTResponseCallBackEventArg*)anArg{
    JNIEnv *env;
    int attach = (*jvm)->AttachCurrentThread(jvm, (void**)&env, NULL);
    if(attach == 0){
        (*jvm)->GetEnv(jvm, (void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_4);
        jmethodID method = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, smartCallbackClass, "callback_onStopClassFailed", "()V");
        (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, smartCallbackObject, method);
    }
    (*jvm)->DetachCurrentThread(jvm);

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How can Java call Objective-C in a Objective-C project. Wasen't the question about calling Java from Obejctive-C. In the beginning of your aswer you "Have first call from the java side to the objective C"?

Comment: Note that you should only detach a thread using `DetachCurrentThread`, which you have attached to the JVM, if **it is not a Java Thread**. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/52342198/942774