# calling java method from c++ using JNI

Tags: java, c++, methods, java-native-interface

i'm trying to wrap a c++ library for a specific usb device in JAVA.
the library supports Callback functions to inform the application about the attachment and detachment of usb device to PC.

the call back function must have a specific format like this:

```
DWORD callbackFunction(void *params);
```

so i implemented a function like this in JNI dll and want to call a function in Java wapper whenever this function is called.

the question is what JNIENV i should use for calling GetObjectClass, GetMethodID and CallVoidMethod from?

---

This is how I initialize my DLL. the "Set(AttachDetach)Callback" methods accept a callback function(first parameter) and a void* parameter(secondparameter) that will be passed to the function when module attach/detach is detected.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MyPackage_MyClass_InitializeDLL
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject callback)
{
      // Storing callback object in global variable.
    callBackObj = callback;

    env->GetJavaVM(&jvm);

    MyInstance = new MyClass();
    MyInstance ->SetAttachCallback(AttachCallBack, &callBackObj);
    MyInstance ->SetDetachCallback(DetachCallBack, &callBackObj);

      // Testing!
    jclass callBackCls = env->FindClass("MyPackage/MyClassCallBacks");
    jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(callBackCls, "attach", "(B)V");
    if (!mid)
        return ; /* method not found */
      //This call here works well
    env->CallVoidMethod(callBackObj, mid, 5);
}
```

then i set a callback function in DLL for the USB device and it is successfully called when i attach the device.

The code i put in attach callback of the USB device is this:

```
DWORD CALLBACK AttachCallBack(CallbackParams* params)
{
    JNIEnv *env;
    jvm->AttachCurrentThread((void **)&env, NULL);

    jclass callBackCls = env->FindClass("MyPackage/MyClassCallBacks");
    jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(callBackCls, "attach", "(B)V");
    if (!mid)
        return -1; /* method not found */
      // This call fails with an access violation Exception
    env->CallVoidMethod(*((jobject *)(params->param)), mid, params->moduleIndex);
      // This fails the same way too
    env->CallVoidMethod(callBackObj, mid, 5);

    jvm->DetachCurrentThread();

    return 0;
}
```

Before i use AttachCurrentThread i wasn't able to use JNIENV pointer at all. but now any other use of this pointer is successful instead of the call to CallVoidMethod.
Do you see what is wrong here?

Let me add that MyPackage.MyClassCallBacks Is an interface that it's method is implemented in another calss namely "callBackClass"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have a reference to the current JVM:

```
JavaVM *jvm;
```

You can add an initilizing method to the C++ backend, which obtains this reference when the program starts:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL init(JNIEnv *env, jclass){
    env->GetJavaVM(&jvm);
}
```

And when observing for USB attachemnt / detachment, you can obtain JNIEnv from this JavaVM like this:

```
JNIEnv *env;
jvm->AttachCurrentThread((void **)&env, NULL);

//your code here

jvm->DetachCurrentThread();
```

This is implemented so that every USB device change creates a new thread. If you use only one thread for the chceking, you need to attach only once (in the initilizer, perhaps?) and you will then have JNIEnv valid as long as your native thread stays attached to the JVM.

Comment: Hi Jakub. thanx for your reply. that solved my problem. But now i encountered another problem one step forward. i can get the jclass and method ID using the JNIENV parameter i obtained from the GetJavaVM method but the call to the function in JAVA(using CallVoidMethod) causes an Access violation Exception. The callback function that i set for the usb device in the native library is called in a new different thread from the main thread.

Comment: Generally, every new thread you want to use with Java must be attached using the AttachCurrentThread(). It will make JVM associate this native thread with a Thread object. If you attemp to call a Java function from a thread that was not attached, you get Access Violation. Post more code and we'll see.

Answer (score 2):

What you may have to do is create a queue in C and wait on it or poll it using a Java thread.  This would always have a current JNIEnv available to it.

---

It seems you can't ...

.... save the JNIENV from the last JNI call which set this up and reuse it.

Your callback appears to return params which you may have passed it when you setup the call back. You can make one of them the JNIENV.

Comment: You should generally *not* save the JNIEnv for later re-use, even though it may occasionally work to do so.  Java callbacks should start with a JVM reference from which they can obtain an appropriate JNIEnv pointer.

Comment: Can you explain how that is done without saving it somewhere?

Comment: The first time you enter JNI-land, you save a reference to the VM (see Jakub's answer).  From the VM reference, you can later retrieve a context-specific JNIEnv pointer.

Comment: yes saving JNI and using it later cuases an access violation exception.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem too. It was as though the reference to the object, created in the initialization method, was of no use in the other methods. And it is indeed like that.
The solution is in the initialization of the reference to the object, which must be initialized not simply with

```
callBackObj = callback
```

but with

```
callbackObj = env->NewGlobalRef(callback)
```

Same issue here: [Objective C calling Java methods using JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539257/objective-c-calling-java-methods-using-jni)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I had to leave that matter as it was and work on another task. but thanks for the reply. seams to be relevant. I will check it(sooner or later). By the way, did you edit your post? the notification was different!

Comment: You are welcome and, by the way, sorry for the late reply.
Did I edit my post? Mmm... may be. It was one of my first answers and I had some issues with the response format. In addition fbfcn corrected my grammar (and I thank him, by the way).

Answer (score 0):

Create a JNI init(JNIEnv * env, jclass c (or jobject o) ) and

```
save param #1 JNIEnv

save param #2 jclass (if static) 
   or 
save param #2 jobject (in non-static)

lookup and save the jmethodID(s) for the Java method(s) you will be invoking.
```

Good idea to also have a JNI shutdown(JNIEnv * env, jclass (or jobject) ) for native shutdown/cleanup